# How can I make multiple asteroids, after making the code for one?

Tags: javascript

I'm using JavaScript to make a game, and I have created one asteroid that moves vertically and picks a random `x` position.

How can I create multiple asteroids that pick random starting points?

Below is what I currently have for the asteroid:

```
//create asteroid
asteroid={
    x:width/2,
    y:-6,
    min:1.6,
    max:2.2,
    speed:1.6
}

// move asteroid
if(asteroid.y<height){
    asteroid.y+=asteroid.speed;
}else{
    asteroid.y=-6;
    asteroid.x=Math.random()*(width-0)-0;
}

//draw asteroid
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "#D9BA5F";
ctx.arc(asteroid.x, asteroid.y,3,0,2*Math.PI,false);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

Comment: This get's 5 votes… huh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make your move and draw routines into methods of the asteroid objects:

```
// Define an Asteroid constructor
function Asteroid(width, height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x = width/2;
    this.y = -6;
    this.min = 1.6;
    this.max = 2.2;
    this.speed = 1.6;
}

// Move asteroid
Asteroid.prototype.move = function() {
    if(this.y < this.height) {
        this.y += this.speed;
    } else {
        this.y = -6;
        this.x = Math.random()*(this.width-0)-0;
    }
}

// Draw asteroid
Asteroid.prototype.draw = function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#D9BA5F";
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 3, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
```

Then you can create multiple asteroids:

```
var asteroids = [];
// create 10 asteroids
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    asteroids.push(new Asteroid(Math.random()*10, Math.random()*10));
}
```

In your main loop, move and draw them all:

```
for(var i = 0; i < asteroids.length; i++) {
    asteroids[i].move();
    asteroids[i].draw();
}
```

---

As pointed out by @blunderboy in the comments, this still doesn't randomize anything you weren't already randomizing. You could use Powerslave's parametrized constructor, where all randomization should take place at instantiation time, or generate at least part of the random values from within the constructor.

Also, passing in the canvas context object instead of relying on a closure would be preferred.

Comment: Nice answer indeed. OP wants to draw asteroids at random position but your code is also randomizing the dimenstions of asteroid. Isn't it ? Look here `new Asteroid(Math.random()*10, Math.random()*10)`

Answer (score 2):

Create a constructor instead of a static JSON object.

```
function Asteroid(x, y, min, max, speed) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
    this.speed = speed;
}
```

Then you can create an asteroid as follows:

```
var asteroid = new Asteroid(width / 2, -6, 1.6, 2.2, 1.6);
```

*Note: this is not the optimal way of doing it, but a pretty simple one to work with. For optimal solution you would apply encapsulation, design patterns, etc.*

EDIT: See bfavaretto's answer for more detail on encapsulating asteroid-related functionality and the whole approach.

Comment: I wish our answers could be combined! :)

Comment: @bfavaretto Hahaha, nice! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone who contributed! This was what I really needed, seeing as there's not much time left for me to complete this game. :)

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a `for` loop and set `n` to the number of asteroids you want when calling the function.

Something like this:

```
function createAsteroid(n) {

   for (var i = 1; i < n; i++) {

     //create asteroid
     asteroid[i] = {
         x : width/2,
         y : -6,
         min : 1.6,
         max : 2.2,
         speed : 1.6
     }

     // move asteroid
     if (asteroid[i].y < height) {
         asteroid[i].y+ = asteroid.speed;
     }
     else {
         asteroid[i].y = -6;
         asteroid[i].x = Math.random() * (width-0) -0;
     }
     return asteroid;
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but the logic-idea behind it is sound.

Comment: You cannot have an assignment like `asteroid + i = something` and also you do not return the resulting object.

Comment: Well, there are several approaches. The seemingly most appropriate one is listed in bfavaretto's and my answer. With your approach, you could, for example simply create an `asteroid` local variable storing reference to the asteroid under construction and the `return` the result at the end of the function or (although I pretty much recommend against using globals) you could alter the line in question to `asteroids[i] = something` with, of course, the `asteroids` global array created in advance.

Comment: ... there still remains the problem that the values for the asteroid are hardcoded instead of being dynamic/randomized. Also, you're applying a hardcoded movement to an asteroid right after "construction".